# How to make Text scrollable in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, text, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I want to create a scrollable Text in Jetpack Compose.

In View system, we can make text scrollable by using:

`android:scrollbars = "vertical"` and
`textview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`

Please help me!

I tried using `Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())` but it doesn't work

Comment: `Text(LoremIpsum().values.first(), modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()))`  works fine to me. Make sure your text content is big enough.

Comment: @Pnemonic I didn't get what're you trying to say? If content is big enough, you vertical scroll is gonna work, otherwise it's not gonna work, this is expected behaviour

Comment: This is *really* basic--why is it so difficult to find straight answers to this very common programming task?

Answer (score 5):

My Solution might be late for you yet I post it here, it might help others :)

I had the same problem and solved it by wrapping my scrollable Text Component into a LazyColumn. But beware! Your content must be big enough, in my case I had a fixed height, which may result in text overflow

```
val scroll = rememberScrollState(0)

    LazyColumn( modifier = ...) {
    item {
        Text(
            text = "YourText",
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(...)
                .height(90.dp)
                .verticalScroll(scroll)
            )
         }
}
```

Comment: How is this even possible, a verticalScroll inside a LazyColumn will crash with an illegalStateException because of infinity maximum heigh constraints

Comment: That's why you need a value for the height property. I have also pointed to this in the explanation.

Comment: How can this be done using the maximum height?